# Setting UIView on the left top corner is broken in ios Emulator/IPhone5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiview

I am trying to display some `UIView` (say, `UIButton` or `UITextView`) right below the top of the screen. I do not use IB nor autolayouts: I am trying to do it manually. I have my status bar *disabled*, hence my `applicationFrame` == `bounds` of default screen.

My UIView's `frame.origin.y` is `0`. 
On IPhone4 and IPad (emulation) it works correctly: I see my element in the left top corner. But when I set emulator to IPhone5 the element is is not displayed (actually, it is displayed above the screen). When I set its `y` to about 50 it is displayed correctly.

Is it an emulation bug or something worng with my code?

Comment: Check the frame of view's superview. It might be possible that superview's  y-coordinate may not be 0. You can set background color to superview to check its position.

Comment: Thanks, but I have both ``frame`` and ``bounds`` 0 for superview. Could it be because I check it in loadView, not in viewdidload?

Answer (score 0):

What version of iOS is the iPhone 4 running?, if its 6 or lower then it will display it correctly.
From iOS 7 and above you have to add the topLayoutGuide to the frame.origin.y of a view if you want it to be below the status bar. Im sure your simulator is running iOS 8, thats why it doesnt display right there.

Comment: IOS is 8.3, you are right. Is that because ``IUViewController`` occupies whole screen since IOS 7? But ``topLayoutGuide`` is ``0``, as well as parentView's one. Could it be because I check it in ``loadView``, not in ``viewdidload``?

Comment: Are you using story board? if so then you can use the "nearest neighbour" popover in the bottom of the constraints menu. Select the top line and click "Add 1 constraint".

This will default your constraint to the top layout guide.

If you are doing that with code with VFL or manually setting frames then let me know I will tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that status bar (the one with battery indicator) is not displayed in IPhone5 emulator even if I turn it on ("status bar is initially hidden == NO"). I scrolled my emulator and found bar and my `UIView`! For some reason IPhone5 (but not Iphone4 nor IPad!) emulator starts with screen scrolled. Probably I created view to big to fit the screen (which is strange because `applicationFrame` is used).